# Multiple Link issue in a Superuser question

Tags: support, markdown

There seems to be an issue in multiple links some how.

I have 2 links in the question below

https://superuser.com/questions/2389/what-is-wolfram-alpha-good-for/2705#2705

The 2nd link is different in the source but it is displayed the same as the first link (the href not the text)

https://superuser.com/posts/2705/edit

```
    The correct answer is: To answer every question your precocious 6- 11 year old has.  When he asks what the largest moon in the solar system is. Or how many gallons of water are in the pacific ocean... Wolfram should have those answers.

    While I realize that not all the databases that will be in Wolfram Alpha are in there now it will they will be.

    Btw the ocean question takes two queries

    [pacific ocean area * pacific ocean average depth][1]

    [convert 1.605x10^8 mi3 to gallons][2]

      [1]: http://www08.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pacific+ocean+area+*+pacific+ocean+average+depth
      [2]: http://www08.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convert+1.605x10^8+mi3+to+gallons
```

Answer (score 7):

I fixed the answer in question for you.  The problem was that it didn't like the `^` character in the second URL.  I encoded it as `%5E`.

Note that the editor preview doesn't appear to like the `*` in the first URL, either, but the server-side Markdown parser is fine with it.

Comment: I don't know if this is a correct answer but I gave it +1 for a work around...  seems like the correct answer would be that the bug was acknowleged/fixed.